# Why chrome reacts after receiving kill-stop signal, and how to prevent that?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, kill

I am trying to save my laptop's battery by pausing/stopping completely chrome from doing stuff while minimized by manually sending it a kill-stop signal.
When I did that, I pressed CTRL+T to test if chrome can create a tab when it is stopped, chrome didn't react with creating a new tab, but I noticed that the title of the window changed from my current tab name to "New Tab", meaning it still somewhat working.

The line I am using for sending kill-stop signal is `sudo kill -STOP $(pidof chrome)`.

How can I completely stop chrome from consuming CPU time for a period of time, and saving all of my session in-memory (not having to exit and launch it again)? And why the method above didn't completely work?

Comment: Are you sure that Chrome is only one process?

Comment: @DaveP `ipidof` returns all processes that contain (or exact match?) the specified name. one or multi-process application is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `pidof` is missing some processes, testing it with Chromium on Debian it returns 17 pid's, while `ps ax|grep [path]` returns 18 pid's.

I'd use this instead, after finding chrome's path with

```
cpath=`which chrome`

pkill -f -STOP "$cpath"
```

Taking advantage of pkill's `-f`:

> -f, --full
>
> The  pattern  is  normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set,
>                 the full command line is used.

Comment: `which chrome` returns nothing, I am using `pkill ... chrome` instead.

Comment: `which` just returns a command's pathname, Maybe chrome isn't in your default path, but it should be visible in the `ps ax` output to confirm too. Not using the path just avoids unfortunately similar named commands, but probably fine without it.